# Unable to call a PostgreSQL function using callable statement or prepared statement

Tags: postgresql, scala, function, stored-procedures

I have created a PostgreSQL function which is tested on the backend side and it works as expected. However, when I am trying to call it through the Scala module it says that the function doesn't exist.

`Function`:

```
create or replace function testing.compareData(ab integer, b json, tablename varchar) RETURNS void as $$
  DECLARE 
  actualTableName varchar := tablename;
  histTableName varchar:= actualTableName ||'_hist';
  job_id Integer:=0;
begin --<<<< HERE
  set search_path to testing; -- Set the schema name
  execute 'SELECT id FROM '||actualTableName||' WHERE id =$1' into job_id using ab;
  -- if there is data for id in the table then perform below operations
  if job_id is not null then
      execute FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I select * from %I where id = $1',histTableName,actualTableName) USING ab;
      execute FORMAT('DELETE FROM %I where id = $1',actualTableName) USING ab;
      EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I values($1,$2)',actualTableName) USING ab,b;
  -- if id is not present then create a new record in the actualTable
  ELSE    
      EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I values($1,$2)',actualTableName) USING ab,b;
  END IF;

END; --<<<< END HERE
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`Callable Statement` Way:

```
def callingStoredProcedure(message: String, id: Integer, resourceType: String): Unit = {
    val connectionUrl: String = ReadingConfig.postgreDBDetails().get("url").getOrElse("None")
    var conn: Connection = null
    var callableStatement: CallableStatement = null
    try {
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)
      callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{ call testing.compareData( ?,?,? ) }")
      callableStatement.setString(1, message)
      callableStatement.setInt(2, id)
      callableStatement.setString(3, resourceType)
      callableStatement.execute()
    } catch {
      case up: Exception =>
        throw up
    } finally {
      conn.close()
    }
  }
```

`Prepared Statement` way:

```
def callDataCompareAndInsertFunction(message: String, id: Integer, resourceType: String): Unit = {
    val connectionUrl: String = ReadingConfig.postgreDBDetails().get("url").getOrElse("None")
    var pstmt: PreparedStatement = null
    var conn: Connection = null
    try {
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)
      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select testing.compareData(?,?,?)")
      pstmt.setInt(1, id)
      pstmt.setString(2, message)
      pstmt.setString(3, resourceType)
      pstmt.executeQuery()
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception => throw e
    }
    finally {
      conn.close()
    }
  }
```

Here, `testing` is my schema under which the function is created. When ran using both the ways it throws below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function testing.comparedata(character varying, integer, character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the exact `create function` statement you used to create the function

Comment: Added function. Please have a glance once

Comment: Would recommend to use some Scala DB lib

Comment: Can you suggest some ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your first parameter isn't a string, so calling `setString(1, ...)` will result in the error you quoted in your question.

Your second parameter is declared as `json` so you can't directly pass a String value there as well. The following should work (given the function definition):

```
  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select testing.compareData(?,cast(? as json),?)")
  pstmt.setInt(1, id)
  pstmt.setString(2, message)
  pstmt.setString(3, resourceType)
```

You might also need to use `pstmt.execute()` instead of `executeQuery()` as your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer. It worked. Just a minor change I had to do is changed `jsonb` to `json` because somehow it wasn't working and same I have edited in your answer. You made my day :)

Comment: Ah, right. I didn't see you were using `json` not `jsonb` (which you should use)

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to be in a binary form because there can be operations performed on that JSON later on by some other modules.

Comment: You don't have to deal with it in "binary form", it's just a different way Postgres _stores_ the values. [quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) "*In general, most applications should prefer to store JSON data as `jsonb`, unless there are quite specialized needs, such as legacy assumptions about ordering of object keys*"

Comment: Ohh, Okay. I will try that too. Thanks for pointing it out. As well as I was little bit curious about the callable statement way. Why that part wasn't working? Is it the same because of that casting?

Comment: In the callableStatement you pass an int as the second parameter (which should be a  String)